why textract dont return TABLES , just return "WORDS" end "LINES"
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

class TextractWrapper:
    """Encapsulates Textract functions."""

    def __init__(self, textract_client, s3_resource, sqs_resource):
        """
        :param textract_client: A Boto3 Textract client.
        :param s3_resource: A Boto3 Amazon S3 resource.
        :param sqs_resource: A Boto3 Amazon SQS resource.
        """
        self.textract_client = textract_client
        self.s3_resource = s3_resource
        self.sqs_resource = sqs_resource
            
    def analyze_file(self, bucket, file_name):
        """
        Detects text and tables in a PDF file stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.
    
        :param bucket: The name of the S3 bucket.
        :param file_name: The name of the PDF file.
        :return: The JobId of the text detection job.
        """
        try:
            response = self.textract_client.start_document_analysis(
                DocumentLocation={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': file_name}},
                FeatureTypes=["TABLES", 'FORMS','SIGNATURES','LAYOUT']
            )
            print(f"Started text detection job with id: {response['JobId']}")
        except ClientError as e:
            print(f"Couldn't start text detection job: {e}")
            raise
        else:
            return response["JobId"]


I using this code end work well with others documents, but with one isnt working. End the strange part it is work when i upload on textract aws directly. But i want to make an automation with lambda end s3.
Try return Tables using boto3 but just return LINES end WORDS

That sounds like a bug to report to AWS really, if you're saying that the API behaves differently to the web console version for one document only. I’m not sure anyone here can help you; I think the best we could do is say your code looks correct (which I can't personally, I don't know this API), but if it works fine for other documents then I assume it is.

I descovered , the textract contains paginations , so NextToken reveals others pages. In this case the reponse was in the next page

Glad you solved it! Please can you post that as an answer below?
